# Interpreting a DMARC report that seems to have conflicting data

Tags: postfix, spf, dkim, dmarc

I recently implemented DMARC in monitoring mode, in order to begin preparing all the domains I manage. Here is the aggregate report for yesterday. I don't understand why DKIM would evaluate to false under policy_evaluated when DKIM is marked pass under auth_results. This domain (mydomain.io) sent one message yesterday (my own server is the SMTP server) to another domain I manage (myotherdomain.net) whose MX is Google Apps.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<feedback>
  <report_metadata>
    <org_name>google.com</org_name>
    <email>noreply-dmarc-support@google.com</email>
    <extra_contact_info>https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466580</extra_contact_info>
    <report_id>xxx711</report_id>
    <date_range>
      <begin>1469923200</begin>
      <end>1470009599</end>
    </date_range>
  </report_metadata>
  <policy_published>
    <domain>my.domain.io</domain>
    <adkim>r</adkim>
    <aspf>r</aspf>
    <p>none</p>
    <sp>none</sp>
    <pct>100</pct>
  </policy_published>
  <record>
    <row>
      <source_ip>23.92.28.xx</source_ip>
      <count>1</count>
      <policy_evaluated>
        <disposition>none</disposition>
        <dkim>fail</dkim>
        <spf>pass</spf>
      </policy_evaluated>
    </row>
    <identifiers>
      <header_from>mydomain.io</header_from>
    </identifiers>
    <auth_results>
      <dkim>
        <domain>myotherdomain.net</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </dkim>
      <spf>
        <domain>mydomain.io</domain>
        <result>pass</result>
      </spf>
    </auth_results>
  </record>
</feedback>`

Comment: Did you post the right report ? That has an SPF pass in auth_results and policy_evaluated. It would likely be more helpful to you if you got an answer for the actual report that failed.

Comment: Yes. Under auth_results I see DKIM and SPF both passed. Above that, in the policy_evaluated node, what does DKIM fail indicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is failing because the domain isn't aligned for DKIM.

The result in `<policy_evaluated>` is assessed as follows:

1. Is the result in `<auth_results>` **pass**?
2. Is the domain in `<auth_results>` aligned? That is, is the domain in `<auth_results>` the same domain as in `<policy_published>`?

If the answers to 1 and 2 are Yes then the result is **pass**, otherwise it is **fail**.

In your case, for DKIM #1 is Yes, but #2 is No because the domain in `<policy_published>` is **mydomain.io** but the domain reported in the `<auth_results>` for DKIM is **myotherdomain.net**.

Comment: myotherdomain.net is the receiving domain.

Comment: According to DMARC Spec, the receiving domain is not reported in RUA reports. How did you set up DKIM for "mydomain.io" ? Are you using the same as the "myotherdomain.net"?

Comment: Can you point me to specs on the RUA reports?

Comment: myotherdomain.net is a Google Apps domain, so everything handled by Google. mydomain.io is my smtp server (Postfix/opendkim), although (1) DNS is handled in the same manager for both domains so it's possible I've screwed up something there and (2) the mydomain.io server *can* send mail from myotherdomain.net so… it sounds like outgoing mail is being signed with the wrong DKIM signature?

Comment: The article on this [link](https://blog.returnpath.com/how-to-read-your-first-dmarc-reports-part-1/) is a brief introduction to the information in the RUA reports.  Also, the section 7.2 of the DMARC Spec [link](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7489#page-30) talks about the RUA reports.

Comment: I agree. I think the DKIM signatures are being mixed and that is what is causing the failure.

Comment: Found the typo buried in my SigningTable. Thanks for your help all around.